# Changing the speed of the moving ball in Canvas pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I'm following this step-by-step tutorial to create a simple MDN Breakout game written entirely in pure JavaScript and rendered on HTML5 .
You can find the link and code here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Move_the_ball. I'm trying to change the speed of the moving ball, I'm new to javascript, so would appreciate your help.

Comment: change value of dx or dy or both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change `dx` and `dy`:

```
var dx = 4;
var dy = -4;
```

or change interval:

```
setInterval(draw, 5);
```

Comment: The second option isn't a good solution, so I wouldn't recommend to promote it in here.

Comment: Thanks it works well! I have another question, is it possible to change the moving ball to a moving image (for example a lemon)? The issue here is the ball is a line drawn.